# A question about John Resig's Simple Javascript Inheritance

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using this simple code: http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/
Using this "library", I made this simple class:

```
var Person = Class.extend({
  init: function(openningSentence) {
    this.say(openningSentence);
  },

  say: function(words) {
    alert(words);
  }
});
```

The problem with this class, is that I can't call a function using the variable "this" (line 3 in the code gives an error: unknown method "say").
Does anybody knoes if there's a solution for this problem?
Btw - I'm using jquery, so if there's a jquery-based solution It'll be great :)

Comment: This really has nothing at all to do with jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ohh, That suddenly worked. But in my real class (not test) it doesn't works :P

Comment: I'll try to fix my real class. Thanks for those who tried to help!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a short, self contained example - http://jsfiddle.net/JgMFE/.  You can see that it works fine using the code you provided along with:

```
(new Person("Hello"));
```

​
It alerts "Hello", just as intended.

Comment: Yes it works, thank you. I was probably drunk when I wrote this question :(

Answer (score 0):

How are you calling the function?

```
var p = new Person();
```

Does that give you the error?

Comment: not to be a buzz killington here, but shouldn't this be a comment?

Comment: Well he left a lot out of the question, so it was intended as a *potential* answer.

Comment: @Andy, not necessarily. The answer to that followup question looks like it will probably be the correct answer.